# USB tethering is Constantly disconnected automatically

Tags: usb, usb-tethering

I use USB tethering to access the internet for my PC, but after enabling USB tethering and using it for about 5 minutes, it disconnects, and I should enable it again on my android phone. What should I do to stop disconnecting automatically?

The USB cable is not broken (It doesn't have any problem with charging).  I bought it about one month ago.
Device: Samsung Galaxy A7 2016
Android version: 7.0

Answer (score 0):

in "Developer Settings"

search for "Default USB configuration"
and select "USB tethering"

Reboot the phone (connected to the PC via USB)
and try to access the internet...